# EF: Avoiding multiple update statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Code like this:

```
var compIds = from p in packinglist.List
              select p.ComponentId;
var components = from c in context.Components
                 where compIds.Contains(c.Id)
                 select c;
 foreach (var item in components)
 {
     item.CurrentSiteId = packinglist.DestinationId;
 }
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Ends up issuing lots of SQL Statements like

```
update [dbo].[Components] set [CurrentSiteId] = @0 where ([Id] = @1)
```

Is there a way to instruct EF (Code First) to issue the following statement:

```
update [dbo].[Components] set [CurrentSiteId] = @0 where ([Id] in (....))
```

Or should I look into using the one of the SQLQuery methods available, or a seperate tool like Dapper or massive or ...?

Comment: I'm interested in the answers too, but based on my experience with EF this looks like a candidate for a SQL Query or a stored procedure (which you can import into EF).

Comment: @Tridus: You should post it as an answer because there is no other way then using direct SQL for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a way to perform bulk updates in EF 4 out of the box. There are some very long, complicated work arounds that end up generating SQL though. I suggest using a stored procedure or T-SQL. Here's a quick T-SQL snippet that I've used in the past:

```
using (var context = new YourEntities())
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand(
                     @"UPDATE Components SET CurrentSiteId = 1 WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for this is just to write that query and use `DbContext.SQLQuery()` to run it. As mentioned, there's no way to do this in EF itself.